# Adding Next Month Programmatically (VBA) to a Dynamic Range Table in Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-2010, date-range, vba

I have a dynamic ranged table [Defined Table Name = MainTable]. I also have code which allows me to find the last cell in *DateRange* (Defined Name Range for Column A).

```
Sub Last_Row_Range()
Dim nextMonth As Range
Set nextMonth = Sheets("MainTable").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
nextMonth.Select
End Sub
```

However, here is what I can't figure out. I want the user to be able to press a button (btnNextMonth), which automatically goes to the last row in *DateRange*, offsets by 1 **AND** **Automatically** adds the next month. Below is a picture of what I am trying to achieve. Thanks in advance guys. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the table to your advantage instead of manually finding the last row and inserting.  Here is an example:

```
Sub Last_Row_Range()
    'Get reference to table
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = Sheets("MainTable").Range("MainTable").ListObject

    'Insert new row in table
    Dim tblRow As ListRow
    Set tblRow = tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

    'Increment previous date by 1 month and place in new row
    tblRow.Range(1, 1) = DateAdd("m", 1, tblRow.Range(0, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

**Tested**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Portland Runner. Works perfectly!